# How do I get a DataFrame with pearsonr correlation coefficient for each month?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

Ok so I have two DataFrames that look like the following. The first is called `load` and the second is called `lmp`.

```
   read_date  hour_ending  reading
0 2016-02-12            1   6.3634
1 2016-02-12            2   6.3418
2 2016-02-12            3   6.3893
3 2016-02-12            4   6.3115
4 2016-02-12            5   6.6118
```

and

```
   read_date  hour_ending    reading
0 2016-02-12            1  30.428136
1 2016-02-12            2  29.709692
2 2016-02-12            3  29.474148
3 2016-02-12            4  29.456977
4 2016-02-12            5  29.574211
```

What I want is for every value in the `reading` column in both DataFrames to be correlated using the first value in `pearsonr` with code that, I think, should look like the following `pearsonr(lmp['reading'], load['reading'])[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

merge or concat your dataframe. or simply make a new one with both columns of corresponding values you want to calculate your correlation.

sample:

```
df = pd.merge(load, lmp, on=['read_date','hour_ending'])
```

use the inate pandas.dataframe correlation function to calculate the correlation of the desired columns:

```
df[['reading_x','reading_y']].corr() ## notice that the columns get automatically renamed on pd.merge() since they had the same name
```

do notice that both series should be the same len

and if using merge, you might run into issues if you do not have a unique key to merge on

alternativaly you could just pass both series to `numpy.corrcoef` function

Comment: That's not producing the results that I am looking for. I'm looking for a table of the same length as the tables that get merged where every month (regardless of year) is producing a correlation. Maybe I needed to clarify that in the question. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: the pearson correlation is a coeficient produced on pairwise series. if you want to calculate it over a specific set of data, all you have to do is apply it to that specific set of data. from your comment it sounds like you want to calculate it over dates with the same month, so thats the series of data you should be passing to the function. so your problem wld be to properly parse the data.